# Using realloc safely

Tags: c, memory-management

I have a problem in the following code:

```
char* temp;
temp=realloc(dish->name,(sizeof(name)+1)*sizeof(char));
if(temp == NULL){
    return DISH_NULL_ARGUMENT;
}
dish->name=temp;
```

`dish->name` is `char*`, this code works! but when in a different function I write: `free(dish->name)`, the program is crashing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is `name`? Using `sizeof` on something that might be a pointer is very scary.

Also, please don't scale allocations by `sizeof (char)`, it's always equal to 1 so it just adds noise and a general sense of the author being confused.

When using `realloc()` to grow something, it's good practice to grow it by more than a single element in most cases, since there's a risk it might grow again. Calling `realloc()` can be quite costly, so you should try to not do it very often.

Comment: Thanks A LOT! the problem was that I used sizeof(name) instead of strlen(name)